# Avoid logback logging conflicts with multiple webapp instance

Tags: java, logback, ear

I have a jboss instance with 2 ear, they both log using its own logback ( + slf4j) config file, loggin in different way and in differnt locations, i see that only one logback config file is loaded, so the other miss the configuration and cannot log. If i shut down an ear the other starts to log correctly.

Does any jboss instance could read only one logback configuration? what should i do?

Thanks

Comment: I find myself in the very same situation, did you manage to solve this issue by any chance?